# Bash Script to create a JSON file

Tags: arrays, json, bash, jq

**Input:**
I have a filename called 'myseedips' with a set of Ip addresses in it in the below structure

```html
10.204.99.15
10.204.99.12
10.204.99.41
```

These can be 'n' number of IP addressess line by line.

**Output**
I have no idea on bash programming. But I have to write a bash script to create a JSON file in the below structure. These IP addresses has to be in a loop, so that the JSON will change/extend depending on the length of myseedips file.

```js
"cassandra": {
        "nodes": [
         {"ip_address": "10.204.99.15","type": "seed"},
         {"ip_address": "10.204.99.12","type": "seed"},
         {"ip_address": "10.204.99.41","type": "seed"}]
    },
```

Also need to add logic to add comma at the end of each node for all nodes except the last. Do not append comma if there is only one node.

**Example:**
May be be something like the below code logic, but in bash programming.

```js
j string
j = `"cassandra": {"nodes": [`
for i =0;i<len(ips);i++ {
    j = j + `{"ip_address": "` + ips[i] + `","type": "seed"},`
}
j = j + `}]}`
```

Thanks
Nissar Sheik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `jq`, you'll need an extra pass to convert from raw text to a workable array but simple:

```
$ jq -R '.' myseedips | jq -s '{cassandra:{nodes:map({ip_address:.,type:"seed"})}}'
```

This yields the following:

```
{
  "cassandra": {
    "nodes": [
      {
        "ip_address": "10.204.99.15",
        "type": "seed"
      },
      {
        "ip_address": "10.204.99.12",
        "type": "seed"
      },
      {
        "ip_address": "10.204.99.41",
        "type": "seed"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Jeff, would you also mind answering my one more question posted in this loop

Answer (score 2):

Further to Jeff's answer, please note that the transformation can be accomplished with a single invocation of jq.  If your jq has the `inputs` filter:

```
jq -Rn '[inputs] | {cassandra:{nodes:map({ip_address:.,type:"seed"})}}'
```

Otherwise:

```
jq -Rs 'split("\n") | {cassandra:{nodes:map({ip_address:.,type:"seed"})}}' ips.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

a template `awk` solution can be

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{print "header"} 
     NR==FNR{c=NR;next} 
            {print "prefix",$1,"suffix" (FNR<c?",":"]")}
         END{print "footer"}' myseedips{,}

header
prefix 10.204.99.15 suffix,
prefix 10.204.99.12 suffix,
prefix 10.204.99.41 suffix]
footer
```

you can replace the header,footer,prefix, and suffix.