# How to use Bash to create arrays with values from the same line of many files?

Tags: json, bash, jq

I have a number of files (in the same folder) all with the same number of lines:

`a.txt`

```
20
3
10
15
15
```

`b.txt`

```
19
4
5
8
8
```

`c.txt`

```
2
4
9
21
5
```

Using Bash, I'd like to create an array of arrays that contain the value of each line in every file. So, line 1 from `a.txt`, `b.txt`, and `c.txt`. The same for lines 2 to 5, so that in the end it looks like:

```
[
   [20, 19, 2],
   [3, 4, 4],
   ...
   [15, 8, 5]
]
```

Note: I messed up the formatting and wording. I've changed this now.

I'm actually using `jq` to get these lists in the first place, as they're originally specific values within a JSON file I download every X minutes. I used `jq` to get the values I needed into different files as I thought that would get me further, but now I'm not sure that was the way to go. If it helps, [here is the original JSON file I download and start with](http://api.citybik.es/v2/networks/valenbisi).

I've looked at various questions that somewhat deal with this:

- [Creating an array from a text file in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30988586/creating-an-array-from-a-text-file-in-bash)
- [Bash Script to create a JSON file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36431371/bash-script-to-create-a-json-file)
- [JQ create json array using bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52087737/jq-create-json-array-using-bash)

Among others. But none of these deal with taking the value of the same line from various files. I don't know Bash well enough to do this and any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `paste` to join the files, then read the input as raw text, splitting on the tabs inserted by `paste`:

```
$ paste a.txt b.txt c.txt | jq -Rc 'split("\t") | map(tonumber)'
[20,19,2]
[3,4,4]
[10,5,9]
[15,8,21]
[15,8,5]
```

If you want to gather the entire result into a single array, pipe it into another instance of `jq` in slurp mode. (There's probably a way to do it with a single invocation of `jq`, but this seems simpler.)

```
$ paste a.txt b.txt c.txt | jq -R 'split("\t") | map(tonumber)' | jq -sc
[[20,19,2],[3,4,4],[10,5,9],[15,8,21],[15,8,5]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, both `paste`  and the `jq` command were extremely useful

Answer (score 3):

Here’s one approach:

```
$ jq -c -n '[$a,$b,$c] | transpose'  --slurpfile a a.txt  --slurpfile b b.txt  --slurpfile c c.txt
```

### Generalization to an arbitrary number of files

In the following, we'll assume that the files to be processed can be specified by *.txt in the current directory:

```
jq -n -c '
  [reduce inputs as $i ({}; .[input_filename] += [$i]) | .[]]
  | transpose' *.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not come up with a simple way, but here's one I got to do this.

## 1. Join files and create CSV-like file

If your machine have `join`, you can create joined records from two files (like `join` command in SQL).
To do this, make sure your file is sorted.
The easiest way I think is just numbering each lines. This works as Primary ID in SQL.

```
$ cat a.txt | nl > a.txt.nl
$ cat b.txt | nl > b.txt.nl
$ cat c.txt | nl > c.txt.nl
```

Now you can `join` sorted files into one. Note that `join` can join only two files at once. This is why I piped output to next `join`.

```
$ join a.txt.nl b.txt.nl | join - c.txt.nl > conc.txt
```

now `conc.txt` is:

```
1 20 19 2
2 3 4 4
3 10 5 9
4 15 8 21
5 15 8 5
```

## 2. Create json from the CSV-like file

It seems little complicated.

```
jq -Rsn '
    [inputs
     | . / "\n"
     | (.[] | select((. | length) > 0) | . / " ") as $input
     | [$input[1], $input[2], $input[3] ] ]
' <conc.txt
```

Actually I do not know detailed syntex or usage of `jq`, it seems like doing:

- split input file by `\n`
- split a given line by space, then select valid data
- put splitted records in appropriate location by their index

I used this question as a reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44781106/10675437